# Background image attachment fixed (parallax) lag/flicks after some scrolls on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image, parallax

I have a problem of lag/flick with my parallax image, I noticed that problem happen after some scrolls of page and only in page where is owl carousel also. I found a lot of solutions but they don't work for me.

I would solve it without use javascript library, can you give me some tips please?

Can you see my problem at this [page](http://demo.webbaku.com/html/tructor/), in the section with title "Contractors & Construction Managers Since 1991."

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.. You can try this code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="title" class="slide header">
  <h1>Pure CSS Parallax</h1>
</div>

<div id="slide1" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="slide2" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-6.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-4.jpg"> 
</div>

<div id="slide3" class="slide">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in velit iudico mandamus sit, persius dolorum in per, postulant mnesarchum cu nam. Malis movet ornatus id vim, feugait detracto est ea, eam eruditi conceptam in. Ne sit explicari interesset. Labores perpetua cum at. Id viris docendi denique vim.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="slide4" class="slide header">
    <h1>The End</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);

html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Nunito;
}

h1 {
   font-size: 250%
}

p {
  font-size: 140%;
  line-height: 150%;
  color: #333;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25vh 10%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    transform-style: inherit;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  transform: translateZ(.25px) scale(.75) translateX(-94%) translateY(-100%) rotate(2deg);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

img:last-of-type {
  transform: translateZ(.4px) scale(.6) translateX(-104%) translateY(-40%) rotate(-5deg);
}

.slide:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.slide, .slide:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;  
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #000;
}

#title {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-6.jpg");
   background-attachment: fixed;  
}

#slide1:before {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-4.jpg");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}

#slide2 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-3.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#slide3:before {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-5.jpg");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}

#slide4 {
  background: #222;
}
```

Comment: I think that this is different from my case. Anyway I tryed some parts of this code and parallax doesn't work.